# Developing Node.js Applications Inside Docker Container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, sails.js

I'm trying to set up my local development environment to the point that all my Node.js applications are developed inside a docker container. Our team works on Linux, macOS, and Windows so this should help us limit some of the issues that we see due to this.

We're using Sails.js for our Node framework, and I'm not sure if the issue is in my Docker setup, or an issue with Sails itself.

Here's my `docker run` command, which almost works:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 --name my-app-dev -v $PWD:/home/app -w /home/app -u node node:latest /bin/bash
```

This almost works, but the application we're developing needs access to the machine's `localhost` for some database applicationss (MongoDB and SQL Server) and to a RabbitMQ instance. SQL Server is on port 1433 (running in Docker), RabbitMQ is on port 5672 (also running in Docker) and MongoDB is on 27017, but not running in Docker.

When I run that Docker command and then start the application, I get an error saying that the application cannot connect to those `localhost` ports, which makes sense from what I've read because by default the docker container has its own `localhost`, which is where it would try to connect by default.

So, I added the following to the `docker run` command: `--net=host`, hoping to give the container access to my machine's `localhost`. This seems to get rid of the issue for RabbitMQ, but not MongoDB. There are two errors in the console for it:

```
2019-09-05 15:58:38.800 | error | error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`myMongoTable`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)
    at Object.teardown (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/index.js:390:19)
    at /home/app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:758:27
    at /home/app/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:20
    at eachOfArrayLike (/home/app/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:13)
    at eachOf (/home/app/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1052:9)
    at Object.eachLimit (/home/app/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3111:7)
    at Object.teardown (/home/app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:742:11)
    at Hook.teardown (/home/app/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/index.js:246:30)
    at Sails.wrapper (/home/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (/home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:56:26)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:67:11
    at beforeShutdown (/home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:45:12)
    at Sails.lower (/home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:49:3)
    at Sails.wrapper [as lower] (/home/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
    at whenSailsIsReady (/home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lift.js:68:13)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iterateeCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:924:17)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:261:22
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1609:17
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:186:25
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iterateeCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:924:17)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
    at afterwards (/home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:350:27)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iterateeCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:924:17)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
    at iteratorCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:996:13)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:233:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
2019-09-05 15:58:38.802 | verbose | verbo: (The error above was logged like this because `sails.hooks.orm.teardown()` encountered an error in a code path where it was invoked without providing a callback.)
2019-09-05 15:58:38.808 | error | error: Failed to lift app: Error: Consistency violation: Unexpected error creating db connection manager:

MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'
}]
    at flaverr (/home/app/node_modules/flaverr/index.js:94:15)
    at Function.module.exports.parseError (/home/app/node_modules/flaverr/index.js:371:12)
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (/home/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:665:56)
    at connectCb (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:335:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

    at Object.error (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/index.js:268:21)
    at /home/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1514:39
    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (/home/app/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:1153:14)
    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (/home/app/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:913:12)
    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (/home/app/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:845:10)
    at /home/app/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:303:7
    at /home/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:952:35
    at Function.handlerCbs.error (/home/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:742:26)
    at connectCb (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/private/machines/create-manager.js:130:22)
    at connectCallback (/home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:428:5)
    at /home/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:335:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

The first issue seems to be related to Sails.js and its `sails-mongo` ORM adapter. The second just seems to be an issue with connecting to the database. So I'm not sure if the first issue is a red herring and its underlying issue is the lack of database connection.

If anyone has any suggestions for how to run a Sails.js app inside a Docker container with access to the machine's `localhost` and MongoDB, I'd love some help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Along with `--network host` in the `docker run` command, you need to define the host's IP in the connection properties and not `localhost`, since localhost in the container refers to the container itself.  If you would like to make connection properties in the code consistent, you can have each developer set up a loopback alias in `/etc/hosts`, e.g. `127.0.0.1    my.host.com` and set the connection properties to that host name ("my.host.com"), e.g. `my.host.com:27017` for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker creates a bridge network and assigns any container attached and the host OS an IP address. Running ifconfig and searching for docker0 interface will show the IP address range that Docker uses for the network.

This is normally quite useful because it isolates any running Docker container from the local network ensuring that only ports that are explicitly opened to the local network are exposed avoiding any potential conflicts.

Sometimes though, there are cases where a Docker container might require access to services for the host.

There are two options to achieve this:

1. Obtain the host IP address from within the container with the code below:

*#get the IP of the host computer from within Docker container*

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

2. You can Attach the Docker container to the local network by running this command:

   **docker run  --network="host"**

If you are using docker-compose you can add a network with host as driver

This will attach the container to the host network, which allows the Docker container to reach any services running on the host via localhost. It also works for any other Docker containers that are running on the local network or have their ports exposed to the localhost.

Comment: I've tried both of those steps, but get the same result no matter what. The connection to Mongo doesn't happen.

Comment: did you try to expose the mongo with port and access via this port ?